# Application rejected from google playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Today my application rejested from google play console and they e-mail and told this
,tell me how i fix the problam and reapply to playsotore
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXeGB.png)

Comment: Is there a question associated with your statements? This is a question and answer site for programming.

Comment: Contact them, they seem to have sent you an incorrectly completed email.